# VSS to SVN - Repositories

Tags: svn, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

We're finally moving from Visual Source Safe to VisualSVN (et al) woohoo.

Is it common practise to just create one repository, and then subsequently add all projects as subfolders of this repository, or create one repository for each project?

Comment: Just as everyone else move from SVN to GIT. No sorry nice move. In my shop we always had a repo per project

Comment: Not everyone.  SVN is still viable, regardless of what Linus says.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to be flippant. We used SVN for a long time very successfully and in the situation it was probably better than DVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version numbers are independent if you create a separate repository for each project.  So project A might be at version 10 and B at 100.

The version number is a running total if you have one repository and a subfolder for each project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one repository, You can give access base on sub folders, so no need for a 2nd repository.

Comment: Well, unless you care for version numbers as @duffymo suggested. I don't usually care for svn version numbers, as they hardly correspond to my project version numbers. (in svn every commit update the version number)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the company. I was a consultant for many years and I have seen different approaches. Following is the most popular approach.

- Each Team creates a repository and stores all their projects in that one repository.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Reference to related question: [SVN project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629670/svn-project-structure/)
It covers if you choose to go with just one repository.